# Setting one animation key also sets another

Tags: animation, godot, gdscript

I have a custom property and when I add it's animation key I also want other animation keys to be added automatically

e.g. if I press `Cusotm Btn` animation key, it should automatically press the `Position` & `Rotation Degrees` key as well

[image]

Is anything like this possible?
(Ideally without having to tamper with `AnimationPlayer` or `Animation` nodes?)

Comment: Messing with `Animation` is precisely what comes to mind. You can look for changes in the `Animation` and add the extra tracks when appropriate.

Comment: @Theraot that was my plan but I was curious just incase I missed something else that I could have used, but if not then I'll post my own answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

had no other choice but to make a custom animation player

```
tool
extends Animation
class_name CustomAnimation


func track_insert_key(track_idx : int, time : float, key, transition : float = 1) -> void:
    .track_insert_key(track_idx, time, key, transition)
    
    var local_node=self.get_local_scene()
    var track_path=track_get_path(track_idx)
    
    var key_node=local_node.get_node(track_path)
    if(key_node.get_class()=="custom_node"):
        var property=track_path.get_subname(0)
        if(property=="custom_prop"):
            remove_track(track_idx)
            var position_track_path=String(track_path).split(":")[0]+":position"
            var position_track_idx=find_track(NodePath(position_track_path))
    
            if(position_track_idx==-1):# if position track does not exist
                position_track_idx=add_track(0)
                track_set_path(position_track_idx,position_track_path)

            track_insert_key(position_track_idx,time,key_node.position)
            
            #do the same for rotation_degrees
            ...
```