# Override animation key being added from node itself?

Tags: godot, gdscript

I'm trying to override the key being added from the node itself,

e.g. if I have a custom property being keyed in animation I could perhaps send a different property and it's value to the animation?

maybe something like this?

```
func get(property:String):
    if(property=="custom_property"):
        return self.position
    else:
        return .get(property)
```

this would equivalent to pressing the position key
[image]

#### *How is this different from your previous question?*

In my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73974048/setting-one-animation-key-also-sets-another/74065471#74065471), I asked if setting one key could also set multiple keys (one key to multiple keys)?

But here I'm asking if there's a one key to one key solution, so maybe this time the information being sent from the node to the animation player can be overridden and add the desired keyframe to the desired track?

**Edit**
A simple explanation would be that when I press the key of `Custom Property` and it would create and insert the track and key of position in the animation player

[image]

I originally wanted to achieve this without having to add any script to the `Animation` Resource

Comment: Bumping this old question: but it sounds like you may have been looking for gdscript's "computed properties" a la `setget`. In the `custom_property` setter you, as per your example, set `position`. In the getter you forward the `position` value.

Comment: You can also use `_get()` and `_set()` the only thing you need to do is keep the same type.

Comment: @hola I'm sorry I don't follow, how would this effect adding keyframe? could you give a minimal code example of what you mean?

Comment: Bumping this again. You can use computed properties to do a couple things in this context: You can use it as a proxy to another value. E.g. you add key frames of "custom\_property" that proxy "position". You can use a boolean property as a button. Clicking on the checkbox will call the "custom\_property"'s setter. The setter can use a reference to the AnimationPlayer and add a keyframe. Lastly, unrelated to computed props, you can create an EditorPlugin. Note: 1. the node doesn't receive any events when the key button is pressed. 2. Proxied properties cannot change types.